# How to do unattended installation for packages which ask the same question?

Tags: apt, kde, deb, configure, kdm

I need to automate `apt-get` installation of `kde-plasma-desktop` which winds up installing both `kdm` and `lightdm` Display Managers.

I'm using `debconf-set-selections` prior to installation to set the following values:

```
# Default display manager:
# Choices: kdm, lightdm
kdm     shared/default-x-display-manager        select  lightdm
lightdm shared/default-x-display-manager        select  lightdm
```

However, when I run `apt-get` I still get prompted during configuration to select the default Display Manager. I've studied the configuration scripts for both packages, but still not getting it. They call `db_input high shared/default-x-display-manager` unconditionally, yet it only asks the question if there was a prior value for the question.

How can I suppress this interaction so it can be run unattended?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, you can always run with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. This will suppress all questions

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install kdm
```

Comment: The good news is that that's indeed non-interactive. The bad news is that it configures the wrong display manager, ignoring (and overwriting) what I put into the database in advance (as specified in my Question). Bug?

Comment: I think I'll file a bug, and either it will be accepted or somebody will point me in the right direction. I'll post the bug and any resolution here when the time comes.

Comment: Bug filed here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339797

Comment: @BobDoolittle KDE is upstream here, I think you should have filed a bug at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/kde-workspace) or [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=kdm;dist=unstable), since this looks like a packaging issue and that's where the package maintainers are.

Comment: My guess is a bug in the kdm configuration script, which is why I filed it there. I could of course be wrong but that's a good place to start I think.

Comment: I notice that it doesn't matter what order the packages are installed, it always winds up prompting, and if run noninteractively it always overwrites the config database with 'kdm'. I tried removing and then reinstalling noninteractively (just) kdm, and then the same thing with lightdm. In both cases the kdm config script overwrites the database with "kdm" even if I am only installing lightdm. So it really does look like a kdm config stript bug to me. Unless somehow I'm not setting the database correctly. debconf-get-selections looks correct, but maybe there is meta-info it's not displaying?

Comment: @muru can you help me out of this problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/536075/what-does-it-mean-to-install-ubuntu-inside-window

Comment: @muru you were right, I had to refile it with Debian. I guess the configuration script belongs to Debian packaging, rather than KDE itself. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=773293