# what does it mean to install ubuntu inside window

Tags: system-installation

i have installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS earlier but it was done easily and flawlessly, but now when i try to install it again from the same cd, it shows to install ubuntu inside windows, where previously it was displayed to install ubuntu along side windows [image]

when i choose the option to continue system reboots and the installation media is ejected,

here is a screenshot of disk management in windows [image]

with all these things i cannot install ubuntu now, please help me get it downloaded

Comment: can you post your disk management snapshot.This will help determine the issue.

Comment: @hunch  By disk management snap do you mean the one displayed when you choose something else

Comment: In window 7, you have the option for Disk management as you have gparted in Ubuntu. Post for window and ubuntu(from live CD or using fdisk)

Comment: @hunch follow this link to view windows partitions from live disk of ubuntu https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=A4EF4793D59C329C&id=A4EF4793D59C329C%212341&v=3

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the selection "Something else" on that screen and this link will help you do just that: 
[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: I concur with daniel. I gather there was some issue you were not made aware of on the previous install.

Comment: can you please guide me to do so manually as my partitions seem to be far more frightening than shown in your link please have a glance at this screenshot https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=A4EF4793D59C329C&id=A4EF4793D59C329C%212341&v=3

Comment: You can use windows disk management to shrink the c: partition however much you want ubuntu to be and then follow the instructions in the link, by creating partitions.

Comment: For External installation(something else), i suggest, first combine 'D and E' and then shrink C to make a new drive for ubuntu. After that boot from live CD and select 'something else' during installation. This is because you can only have 4 primary partition(or 3 primary+1 extendable).

Answer (score 1):

You have four primary partitions, so you won't be able to create new partitions without deleting one first. I think you have installed Windows on the 420 GB partition (C: drive), so you can copy the stuff from one of the 20 GB partitions to C: drive and either:

1. Delete that 20GB partition, and install Ubuntu in the free space created, or
2. Install Ubuntu on to that 20GB partition, after formatting it as `ext4`.